# Fill form with mechanize from variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I am trying to setup mechanize in ror to fill and submit a form, in order to be able to crawl the search results of the next page.

I have tracked down the code to where the error happens. It works perfectly when I hardcode the form variables like this:

```
  form['l'] = 'salzburg'    # location (works)
  form['t'] = 'all:rental'  # SELECT 'all:sale' (works)
  form['pf'] = 1            # price from (works)
  form['pt'] = 800          # price to (works)
  form['rf'] = 2            # rooms from (works)
  form['rt'] = 5            # rooms to (works)
```

but as soon as I try to fill the form from variables it does not submit the form anymore:

```
  pf = @criterium.price_from.to_i.to_s
  pt = @criterium.price_to.to_i 
  rf = @criterium.rooms_from.to_i 
  rt = @criterium.rooms_to.to_i 

  puts pf   # successfully logs => 1
  puts pt   # successfully logs => 800
  puts rf   # successfully logs => 2
  puts rt   # successfully logs => 5

  form['l'] = @criterium.location    # location (works)
  form['t'] = 'all:rental'           # SELECT 'all:sale',
  form['pf'] = pf                    # price from (doesn't work)
  form['pt'] = pt                    # price to (doesn't work)
  form['rf'] = rf                    # rooms from (doesn't work)
  form['rt'] = rt                    # rooms to (doesn't work)
```

strangely, the puts pf, pt, rf, rt commands successfully log the variables to the console.

But submitting fails..

```
page = agent.submit(form)
```

There is no error output, I just see by `puts page.title` before and after the submit, that it stayed on the same page (=which means that the form wasn't submitted).

Appreciate every hint on why the form is not filled from variables.

Comment: You have to switch pages

Comment: You should inspect `form.fields`